# how to delete value from array using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

can you please tell me how to how to delete value from array using jquery ?.I am able to delete values But in place of value I am getting undefined value.

```
items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
if(items.indexOf('c') !== -1) {
  delete items[items.indexOf('c')];
}
console.log(items)
alert(items)
alert(items.length)
```

It is printing 4 length.It is taking undefined value in array.How to remove completely from array ?
So that it length become 3.and out put become a,b,d

Comment: why would you want to use jQuery for such a task? Just use freakin' JavaScript already! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/remove-specific-element-from-an-array

Comment: I need to search first string..

Comment: you should mark @Kong answer as correct if that helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JavaScript Array's built in [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method:

```
array.splice(index, 1);
```

The second parameter is the number of elements to remove, so 1 = "just this one".

Comment: "c" may be at any place.So First I need to get the index of c ?

Comment: Then use `indexOf()` method along with this one.